# Python ---module 'numbers' has no attribute Number

Tags: python-3.x

I have problem with import [PdfFileReader], so when I type the Python shell this command
"from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader"
I got the following results:

```
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
1
2
3
.
.
.
97
98
99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyPDF2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .generic import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    import decimal
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

Please any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Try this: sudo -H pip install PyPDF2 then use import PyPDF2

Comment: how could this command go with mac terminal?

Comment: sudo su,          then ->                           pip3 install PyPDF2

Comment: @Mohammed You can check homebrew for mac.

Comment: it is already installed..^^

Comment: $ pip3 show PyPDF2
Name: PyPDF2
Version: 1.26.0
Summary: PDF toolkit
Home-page: http://mstamy2.github.com/PyPDF2
Author: Mathieu Fenniak
Author-email: biziqe@mathieu.fenniak.net
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:

Comment: I couldn’t figure out, how to fix this error...